# Token issue httr salesforce API

Tags: r, salesforce, token, httr

I am calling api from salesforce. I generated token using this code

```
# salesforce --------------------------------------------------------------
sf_token <- salesforcer::sf_auth()
 saveRDS(sf_token$token, "st.rds")
```

Then this code :

```
salesforce::sf_auth(token = "st.rds")
```

I tried to reuse the token. Everything is working fine when I do it in my local computer, but when it comes to time scheduler or aws server, token seems useless with this error information:
Error: Cannot read token from alleged .rds file:
st.rds
Execution halted.
Does anyone know what happened? Thanks

Comment: I would recommend checking the working directory being used when your script executes. It's likely not finding "st.rds" in that path. I answered a similar question in the issues of the **salesforcer** package here: https://github.com/StevenMMortimer/salesforcer/issues/45